# How to give each integer in a list an ID and a name?

Tags: javascript, c#

(beginner coder here)
I'm trying to make a program in which you can play a card game. I created an integer list and included the numbers 1 - 54, each representing a different card. However, I need to show the cards in the player's hand in text (e.g four of hearts). I only have integers representing the cards and I can't think of a way to assign every number in the list a name without using a lot of if statements. So is there a way to give every integer in the list an ID (for example, a number) and a name (for example, the name of the card) like in javascript arrays? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you been taught Object Oriented Programming? Do you know how to make a class, and define properties for that class?

Comment: A deck of cards contains 52 cards (are you counting the jokers?).  How are you modeling a card?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code (even pseudo-code or js)?

Comment: It's all good, I just realized I could use a two-dimensional list. Thanks for all the replies though.

Comment: Using a two-dimensional list to model a deck of cards is the wrong approach.  It might work, but its wrong.  Make a class to model your cards, then have a list of that class instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use a Dictionary instead of a list, if you are using c# you can make a dictionary very easily, just like a list actually.

```
Dictionary<int, string> cardsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

The way the dictionary works is that the first parameter(int) will be your access key to a value, the value is the second parameter(string), in this parameter you can add the card name "four of hearts".

Here is a link of the microsoft docs that can help you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8

And if you're using javascript things will be more complicated, because js doesn't have a native Dictionary class, you will have to implement one yourself, or you can search for one online(github, google, etc).

Edit : As some of you guys in the comment pointed out, it would be smarter to use classes instead of a Dictionary, but i suggested the use of a dictionary because it would be most simple way to solve the problem

Comment: What is the key for 'four of hearts'?  What's the key for 'four of diamonds'?

Comment: A Dictionary probably the wrong approach here. As we said in the comments, create a class to represent the cards, then maintain a list of those.

Comment: yes, i agree that classes could be better, but i wanted to solve the problem in the fastest/simplest way possible

Comment: You should REALLY avoid "the fastest/simplest way." Especially for somebody who is learning still. Why teach a newbie to cut corners? Outside of that it takes all of 15 seconds to create a class and use that instead of a dictionary. You aren't saving meaningful time, just making adaption/maintenance harder later.

Comment: Also your comment about javascript doesnt make much sense. Javascripts base "object" type works almost exactly the same as a dictionary. `var cardsDictionary = { 1: "Ace of Spades" ...}` would work exactly the same as your answer